# Problems accessing samba shares on Ubuntu server with Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, samba, windows-10

I've recently had to restore my Windows 10 system from a working image but since I did it my Samba shares no longer work.

The server has been installed for a couple of years with a stable /etc/samba/smb.conf which always just worked! Since I restored my Windows 10 PC, which has the server name in the hosts file and can connect to the server via ssh2 in a terminal session, just cannot maintain a stable connection to the shared folders in Windows Explorer. For starters it takes a long time for it to list the shared directories, then when you click into one of them, it lists the contents, then seems to want to keep refreshing the display! If you try and descend into directories within the share it will typically lose all contact saying "Windows cannot access \Server". Bizarre. If I then restart samba service on the server I can then see the shares again but can't get as far as copying a file to the Windows machine.

This is really perplexing me - seems like a problem at the windows end, but i'm really out of ideas.

Here's a section from my smb.conf:

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes


# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
read only = no


# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
create mask = 0775


# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
directory mask = 0775




[data]
comment = Data
path = /data
browseable = yes
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
read only = no


[data2]
comment = Data2
path = /data2
browseable = yes
directory mask = 0775
create mask = 0775
read only = no
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the samba connection some time back. I was suggested to add the following into the smb.conf:

[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP

security = SHARE

interfaces = eth0 lo

bind interfaces only = yes

You may need to modify the workgroup and the interfaces as per your requirements.